# access and modify data of different partials using controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 partials with many ng-models in each of them.

partial1.html

```
<input ng-model="A" /> //user enters a
<input ng-model="B" /> //user enters b
<input ng-model="C" /> //user enters c
<button ng-click="SavePartialOne()> Save and go to partial 2 </button>
```

partial2.html

```
<input ng-model="P" /> //user enters p
<input ng-model="Q" /> //user enters q
<input ng-model="R" /> //user enters r
<button ng-click="SavePartialTwo()> Save and go to partial 3 which is by now populated from all the data filled in partial1 and 2 </button>
```

partial3.html

```
<input ng-model="X" /> //angular binds this to auto-populate data from A input box
<input ng-model="Y" /> //auto-populate data from A and P input box
<input ng-model="Z" /> //auto-populate slightly modified data from A input box ilke a is changed to a+1
```

What I need to do is mentioned as comment in all the partials.
Help me with app.js here, i.e. how I'll access and return this data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change all `ng-model` to be available in your object like:

```
<input ng-model="dataModel.A" />
<input ng-model="dataModel.B" />
<input ng-model="dataModel.C" />
<button ng-click="SavePartialOne()> Save and go to partial 2 </button>

<input ng-model="dataModel.P" />
```

And so on so that we can easily read and organize the value of these data in `SavePartialTwo` method do the following:

```
$scope.dataModel = {};

$scope.SavePartialTwo = function() {
    $scope.dataModel.X = $scope.dataModel.A;
    $scope.dataModel.Y = $scope.dataModel.A + ' ' + $scope.dataModel.P;
    $scope.dataModel.Z = $scope.dataModel.Z + 1;

    // Then display your 3rd partial
};
```

Comment: any optimal way to this? i've like 50 such input boxes on each partial. 
And while moving from one partial to another how can I keep the state saved?